# WinWaitActive function isn't behaving as expected

Tags: loops, autohotkey

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but I have an application in which pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> will switch to fullscreen.  I simply want this to happen every time I <kbd>tab</kbd> back to this window.

With the following code, nothing happens at all.

```
#SingleInstance force
Loop
{
WinWaitActive, MyProgram
{
Send, ^{Enter}
WinWaitNotActive, MyProgram
}
}
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` is the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> modifier, you want to use `!{Enter}`.

Try this:

```
#SingleInstance, Force
Loop {
    WinWaitActive, MyProgram
    Send, !{Enter}
    WinWaitNotActive, MyProgram
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand your code will send constantly `!{Enter}` (not one time) until active window is changed. In question as I understand there is a need to send `!{Enter}` only once when window is active to make window fullscreen.

Comment: This achieves what I want, actually better than the other suggestion, but as Vasili111 said, it would be a resource hog since it's constantly firing.  Any way to stop that?  Thanks for the ! ^ correction :)

Comment: I just realized that it also sends the cursor to the top left of the screen, which is slightly bothersome.  Ideally it would be unchanged, or if that's not possible, center screen.

Comment: @vasili111 Are you sure? I'm pretty sure `WinWaitNotActive` holds all further execution indefinitely until the window is no longer active. You can try this by changing `Send, !{Enter}` to `Send, a` or something and use it with Notepad.

Comment: @Jularith The script should not effect your cursor. If the cursor is getting moved by the program you could try using [`MouseMove`](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/MouseMove.htm) to move it back. Also, it shouldn't hog any resources since all execution will be put on hold until your window stops being the active one, and even then AHK barely uses any resources to begin with.

Comment: @Sidola You are correct!  I did some further testing.  Thanks again for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

**Version 1**

```
StateVar := 0
Loop
{
    IfWinActive, MyProgram
    {
        if (StateVar = 0)
        {
            Send, !{Enter}
            StateVar := 1
        }
    }
    else
    {
        StateVar := 0
    }
}
```

**Version 2**
Use in version 2 only part of WinTitle (in your case `MyProgram`). For example `Notepad` instead of `Untitled - Notepad`. It can be helpful if Wintitle of your window changes.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
StateVar := 0
Loop
{
    IfWinActive, MyProgram
    {
        if (StateVar = 0)
        {
            Send, !{Enter}
            StateVar := 1
        }
    }
    else
    {
        StateVar := 0
    }
}
```

**Version 3**

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
    StateVar := 0
    Loop
    {
        IfWinActive, MyProgram
        {
            if (StateVar = 0)
            {
                ControlSend,, !{Enter}, MyProgram
                StateVar := 1
            }
        }
        else
        {
            StateVar := 0
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to achieve (thanks!), although I'm finding that it's only working every-other time I tab to the window.  Very strange.

Comment: @Jularith Maybe WinTitle of your program changes? Try my Version 2.

Comment: No luck there :\  As far as I can tell, the window title is static.  Thanks for the input though, wish I could upvote but I'm brand new here.